# What is the algorithmic complexity of string slicing? (Practical, Real World)

Tags: javascript, big-o, v8

In modern, v8 Javascript, what is the algorithmic complexity of String.prototype.slice?

To be clear, I'm looking for real-world, practical figures or rules of thumb.

#### Quick Tests

I tried to get a rough estimate by running two quick tests in the most recent Chrome. Test 1 slices a string of length `N` in half. Test 2 slices a string of length `N` each index in the string (so `N` times). Confusingly, both run in `O(N)` time. What is going on?

#### Test 1

```
let input = '';
let string = ' '.repeat(20000000);
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    input += string;
    console.time(i);
    const y = input.slice(i / 2);
    console.timeEnd(i);
}
```

#### Test 2

```
let input = '';
let string = ' '.repeat(20000000);
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    input += string;
    console.time(i);
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        const y = input.slice(j);
    }
    console.timeEnd(i);
}
```

Chrome version: Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be `O(n)`?

Comment: If it were `O(n)`, the second test would be `O(n^2)`

Comment: What do you mean by each "trial" in the context of this problem? Is it the code between `console.time` and `console.timeEnd`?

Comment: "*both run in O(N) time.*" makes no sense. `O(n)` is a complexity class, but you don't seem to be measuring with different input sizes at all. Also, what does `n` denote - the length of the source string, the length of the result string, the index? Please instead include the millisecond values that your measurements have yielded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, V8 has [optimised string slicing to `O(1)`](http://mrale.ph/blog/2016/11/23/making-less-dart-faster.html). This does of course depend a lot on what else happens to all the strings, they might need to get copied later on.

The relevant implementation from the above link is:

[image: Sliced String diagram]

```
// The Sliced String class describes strings that are substrings of another
// sequential string.  The motivation is to save time and memory when creating
// a substring.  A Sliced String is described as a pointer to the parent,
// the offset from the start of the parent string and the length.  Using
// a Sliced String therefore requires unpacking of the parent string and
// adding the offset to the start address.  A substring of a Sliced String
// are not nested since the double indirection is simplified when creating
// such a substring.
// Currently missing features are:
//  - handling externalized parent strings
//  - external strings as parent
//  - truncating sliced string to enable otherwise unneeded parent to be GC'ed.
class SlicedString: public String {
  // ...
};
```

---

Also beware of your quick test results. As you are doing nothing with the `y` variable, the slicing and even the whole loop might get eliminated as dead code by the optimiser. If you are doing benchmarks, do them on practical real world data.

Comment: Ok, so when will it be `O(n)` and when will it be `O(1)`? Is there a good rule of thumb? 

I also ran a test where I copied it just once and it was `O(n)` as well. Updated the question description accordingly.

Comment: V8 developer here. This answer is correct. In fact, string slicing is so fast that your benchmark doesn't even measure it. All the time is spent in allocating the crazily big input strings (up to 1 billion characters!). And that allocation is, of course, linear in the size of the string. It shows up in your timed range because *creating* them as "cons strings" is fast and it's the *flattening* that takes the time, which is done on demand (i.e. for the first `.slice` call). Beware of microbenchmarks, they are often misleading!